# Makefile error: Missing separator

Tags: c++, makefile, autotools, anjuta

ALL,

Here is the beginning of my Makefile:

```
# =========================================================================
#     This makefile was generated by
#     Bakefile 0.2.9 (http://www.bakefile.org)
#     Do not modify, all changes will be overwritten!
# =========================================================================


@MAKE_SET@

prefix = /usr/local
exec_prefix = ${prefix}
datarootdir = ${prefix}/share
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c
EXEEXT = 
WINDRES = @WINDRES@
SETFILE = @SETFILE@
NM = /usr/bin/nm -B
BK_DEPS = @BK_DEPS@
srcdir = /home/igor/dbhandler/dbhandler
top_srcdir = /home/igor/dbhandler
LIBS = 
LDFLAGS_GUI = @LDFLAGS_GUI@
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g -O0 -std=c++11
CPPFLAGS = 
LDFLAGS = 
WX_LIB_FLAVOUR = @WX_LIB_FLAVOUR@
TOOLKIT = @TOOLKIT@
TOOLKIT_LOWERCASE = @TOOLKIT_LOWERCASE@
TOOLKIT_VERSION = @TOOLKIT_VERSION@
TOOLCHAIN_FULLNAME = @TOOLCHAIN_FULLNAME@
EXTRALIBS = @EXTRALIBS@
EXTRALIBS_XML = @EXTRALIBS_XML@
EXTRALIBS_GUI = @EXTRALIBS_GUI@
CXXWARNINGS = @CXXWARNINGS@
HOST_SUFFIX = @HOST_SUFFIX@
SAMPLES_RPATH_FLAG = @SAMPLES_RPATH_FLAG@
SAMPLES_CXXFLAGS = @SAMPLES_CXXFLAGS@
wx_top_builddir = @wx_top_builddir@
```

I am getting following error:

Makefile:8 missing seaparator. Stop.

Trouble is I don't think line 8 should be tabbed as it is just "@MAKE_SET@". But most importantly I wonder where this error coming from. I'm using Anjuta to generate the Makefile and just curious why this error shows up.

Thank you for any information.

Comment: What is @MAKE_SET@ supposed to do? That's not valid makefile syntax.

Comment: Are you sure this should be a Makefile, and not an autotools Makefile template?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, the file name is Makefile and this is what generated by Anjuta, which is based on autotools. But I'm not sure about anything. This file is produced inside my_project/Debug/my_project and its called Makefile.

Comment: @immibis, I have no idea. The file is auto generated with this content.

Comment: @Igor Don't get lost with tools you don't actually understand.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, so what would be you recomendation. I can post am/in files that Anjuta generated. Also, that's why I'm trying to use IDE, but it looks like I screwed up somewhere between MSVC, Anjuta and Git.

Comment: @Igor I'd suspect your tool is supposed to generate a `Makefile.in` and you have to apply the `configure` script generated by autotools to get the actual `Makefile`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, What would you suggest? I can try to start from scratch in Anjuta backing up the current code. And then compare backed up version with the new one. Its not that big of a deal. Project is not really big. Any other suggestions.

Comment: @Igor I have no clue what _`Anjuta`_ is supposed to do in your development process. So it's hard to give you some concise answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I'm using Anjuta to do development - edit the code, generate the build script (Makefile) and debug it. But it looks like when I tried to push the code from MSVC to GitHub I somehow overwrote on of the helper Makefiles and now the IDE is failing to generate everything properly. I will probably start from the beginning and when done compare the results. Thank you.

Comment: If you're using version control, why not just find the revision where it broke?

Answer (score -1):

In a makefile, you have a syntax like this:

```
all:
<tab>#yourcode
```

The tab is important. This isn't the right makefile syntax.

Comment: It actually *is* correct Makeile syntax. A makefile accepts definition of 'constants' (or 'variable') to make the rest of the files easier to interpret. The `@MAKE_SET@` is probably wrong here, and I doubt that Anjuta created it. But it is also incorrect to edit the Makefile itself. It will be overwritten as it is generated from Makefile.am